# Display output of a table in Range

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, range, recursive-query

I have below table, where i need to output of all the numbers in this table, if HIGH is blank then the number is inserted as is, if HIGH is not blank then its a range and all the values between LOW and HIGH will be inserted.

```
LOW     HIGH
1031    
1100    
3000    3999
1400    1499
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect., as tabular text.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for a recursive cte, which are available in SQLite starting version 3.8.3.

```
with recursive cte as (
    select low, high from mytable
    union all
    select low + 1, high from cte where low < high
)
select low val from cte
```

This gives a resultset with a unique column called `val`, that contains all values in each range; for records where `high` is `null`, a single row is generated having value `low`.